# How to do drag and drop from file system to browser using Selenium Web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a requirement, where I have to drag images(jpeg or png) form a file and drop it to browser.
I am using Selenium Web Driver as automation tool with JAVA, I tried but selenium doesnt support  anything outside browser.

I need help can anyone guide me how can I  automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use **autoit** for it.

[Drag and Drop](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/122881-files-drag-drop/)

Comment: have you done any kind of automation using autoit for drag and drop.??

Comment: @Umeshlghe Never needed such autoit script but a bit googling gives me this
[link](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/122881-files-drag-drop/)

Answer (score 3):

You would not be able to do this using selenium. The *selenium bindings* have access to the browser instance (the `WebDriver`) but to nothing outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to drop your image into some sort of input you could try this. I used this to upload files with selenium.

```
WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='MyInputField']");

inputField.sendKeys("path to image");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to drag image from desktop to a browser.

Comment: Usually if your dragging the image into a browser your targeting an element to drop the image into. This element (the drop location) you load into a WebElement then you element.sendKeys("C:/Users/'your user'/Desktop/image.jpg"); Selenium will then send the path of the image to your element thus sending the image into your browser.

Comment: @Falkenfighter..
I tried your solution but its not working. Is it working for you??

Comment: Yeah I have a method set up that I can pass the xpath to the element and the path to the file. It then finds the element and then does element.sendKeys(file) I believe this will only work for fields marked for input of some kind. When you say you need to drag it to the browser, is there any part of a webpage that you need to drop the pic into?

Comment: ::I can drop the image anywhere on the browser page.

Comment: hmm if you do not have an element on a webpage you are able to input your image into, or in your case it looks like the browser itself is trying to take control of the image? Then I would look into Autoit. Selenium is great when working with html, javascript, websites. But if your trying to interact with the browser outside of a webpage your going to need to use another tool. Good luck!